# Ruby on Rails - TinyMce works for new but not for edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce, editor

Hey guys I have this form for the NEW action that works with tinyMce

```
<%= f.input :titulo, :label => "Título" %>
<%= f.input :sumario, :label => "Sumário", :input_html => { :class => 'tinymce' } %>
<%= f.input :texto, :label => "Texto", :input_html => { :class => 'tinymce' } %>
<%= f.input :imagem, :label => "Imagem" %>
<%= f.input :ativa, :label => "Ativar/Desativar?", as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline %>
<%= f.input :destaque, :label => "Em Destaque?", as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline %>
```

It's actually a partial that the EDIT action will use aswell. The thing is that the tinyMce editor only shows on NEW and never shows on EDIT.

!!!EDIT: NEVER MIND! RESOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER MIND!

dumb question!

just needed to add this on top of the page:

```
<%= tinymce_assets %>
```

and this on the bottom:

```
<%= tinymce %>
```

I didn't have this on EDIT xD SORRY FOR THE QUESTION